# Access denied when sending data to Amazon S3 through Kinesis Firehose using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have the following pipeline:

EC2 ---> Kinesis Firehose ---> S3

I have a Python script running in the EC2 that tries to send records to the Kinesis Firehose which in turns put them inside the Amazon S3 bucket. I am using put_records from boto3:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
client = session.client('firehose')

response = client.put_record(
           DeliveryStreamName='my-kinesis-firehose',
           Record={
                'Data': data ## Json data
            }
        )
```

I have set my AWS credentials in ~/.aws/credentials. I also used the creation wizard for setting up the correct IAM role for Firehose to be able to access Amazon S3.

When running the above code, I can see in the Firehose monitoring screen that it is receiving data. However, here are the records that I see in the Amazon S3:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DJHKLHANZKDJN</RequestId>
<HostId>
z1YRkwTZQ9fbEkcvjdksnfkezjXCKJhbnkajzdnkjDJ0VDh/PPegqacT9+qynpXtkZ2ObDcQ8xtIQNje3M=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I also tried to assign an IAM role to the EC2, but still same results.
The response of put_record seems good (HTTPstatus code 200, no error), and since I am being able to send data to Firehose the issue is not in the EC2 credentials.
Any idea ?

Comment: This means that you don't have access to your S3, or firehose? It seems to me that it is only you (your IAM user) who can't read those objects?

Comment: You mean that I am just not able to read the object but it has been inserted correctly ? I am trying to read it from the AWS dashboard, am I not supposed to have all access as the root user .?

Comment: Are you able to check with AWS CLI if you can get any file created by Firehose?

Comment: @Marcin that was it, I used a different role to create the object, and the root one did not have access. Using the correct creds with AWS CLI did solve the issue. Thanks.